# Equivalent expression to: "I don't give a f***"

Tags: word-choice, equivalent-phrase

Is there something in Mandarin like "I don't give a f***", something that expresses the same sense of "I don't care" but with more force.

Comment: `关我屁事(guan1 wo pi4 shi)~`? :p

Comment: 关我鸟事 (guan1 wo niao3 shi)~?

Comment: a similar network idiom in Chinese is 我是打酱油的

Comment: +1 [And not a single f*** was given that day](http://i.stack.imgur.com/hk5qm.jpg)

Comment: @NullUserException: nice, can we put it the chinese into the passive voice and get a nice translation of that :p

Comment: Sorry to use Chinese. 本来“屌”和“鸟”是同音的（均为“屌”的音），后来人们觉得这样太不好了，就把鸟的读音变成niao了。@macskuz所以其实“关我鸟事”也是“关我屌事”的意思。《水浒传》里面经常用“鸟”来代替“屌”。

Comment: @zsh222 Wow this explains a lot, and I just checked Old Chinese pronunciation and thinking you are right... (鳥 *teəw by 周法高 for example)

Comment: For the original question, 关我屁事 is closest in my mind XDD (In Taiwan 干我屁事 is more common)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, but in the dialect spoken where I lived people say 没得屌事.

Comment: People in NanJing like this expression,but it's sounds a little vulgar.

Comment: yes, 屌 means cock,but a HongKong famous singer named ZhouJieLun(周杰伦) use this word very often,many many young peope follow him in mainland of China,so it is used very common in all China area.

Comment: ZhouJieLun is a Taiwanese singer. The 屌 is used slightly differently and with border context in Hong Kong than in mainland China.

Comment: @Huang Yes, I live in Nanjing. That's really a daily use phase for every Nanjinger.

Answer (score 3):

Strong but not vulgar answer: 我才不管

Example:

> I don't give a f*** what he thinks

Translation,

> 我才不管他想什么呢

Answer (score 2):

A direct translation would be:"我不在乎".

If you want to make an emphasis or show your anger, you could say:"爱咋咋的".
"爱咋咋的" is more commonly used in Northern area, which literally means "[do] anything you like to[, I don't care.]", you can also simply say "随便”.

Answer (score 2):

管他妈的, why didn't anyone suggest this?

Answer (score 1):

Another - not very vulgar - option is 我不管.